# SOSL on Permission Sets error when no ID is included

Tags: sobject, permission-sets, sosl

I am testing SOSL's on Permission Sets for something I am building and noticed that if I don't include the ID in the fields to request, the search fails:

> An unexpected error occurred. Please include this ErrorId if you contact support: 1061111798-43355 (918623204)

I have seen in many documentation examples that the ID is ommited from the requested fields when executing SOSL queries (on different object types).

For example, if I query Contact's:

```
FIND {"john"}IN Name Fields RETURNING Contact (Name)
```

Works.

However

```
FIND {"some String"}IN Name Fields RETURNING PermissionSet (Label)
```

Fails with the above error

This also works:

```
FIND {"some String"}IN Name Fields RETURNING PermissionSet
```

(Returns the ID's)

Is it mentioned somewhere in the documentation that the ID must be inclduded in the fields to return for certain object types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's an Internal Server Error, it's time to get in touch with support. There's no reason why this particular SOSL should fail when others do not. The ID field should always automatically be included by the SOSL/SOQL engine. Curiously, the SOSL only fails if it returns at least one result; if there are no results, it completes normally.

Comment: guess i will contact support =) - thanks for the insight